# Why in2csv not converting my XLSX file with non-ascii sheet title? [CentOS x64]

Tags: php, excel, csv, xlsx, csvkit

My problem is that I have an Excel XLSX file with non-ascii sheet name (`Общий отчет`) and I'm trying to convert it to CSV using in2csv tool. I run it from PHP using `exec` function.

On my local machine (Windows 10 x64) it's workong OK. I'm trying to run it on the CsntOS x64 VDS, and when I start my PHP script (which uses `exec` to call in2csv tool) from terminal - it works OK too. But when I run it from cron (`php -f ./task.php`) - it produces no error but the resulting CSV file is blank!

I did some tests, checking user and group running PHP script, python default encoding, but still have no clue. Please help!

Here is the command to convert the file:

```
in2csv --locale ru_RU --sheet "Общий отчет" --encoding windows-1251 "prices.xlsx" > "prices.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

The command in PHP's `exec` function should look like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/in2csv --locale ru_RU --sheet "Общий отчет" --encoding windows-1251 "/home/admin/www/html/prices.xlsx" > "/home/admin/www/html/prices.csv"');
```

And the cron command should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/admin/www/html/task.php
```

That is, you need to provide full paths to all executables, and this will work both in terminal and in Cron!